# Mobile Push SDK ContactKey requirements

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

We are implementing Mobile Push into our App, part of the SDK requires us to registerContact within MC. This requires us to query the Salesforce ID internally to set the appropriate Contact Key up. I wanted to confirm only on registration this key is required, or will it need to be initiated each time the app is launched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have set the contact key in the SDK it will be retained by the SDK and sent with all future registration updates to the Marketing Cloud.

Comment: Are there any scenarios where we'd need to set the Contact Key again? Aside from registration?

Comment: For a given installation of the application and for the same contact, no.  If the app is uninstalled from the device (or data is cleared) then you would need to set it again.